# PlayFramework: Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalax/io/Seekable

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I have just downloaded the play 2.2.2.RC2 however, when i run `play` command this is the output i get. What am i doing wrong?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalax/io/Seekable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:201)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:198)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scalax.io.Seekable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 33 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scalax/io/Seekable
```

Comment: Update: Although this might not be particularly helpful to anyone, I resulted to the classic "when in doubt restart". I cleaned up .ivy, .sbt, deleted and re-downloaded play. Now it works, but i am still very curious as to what caused this.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need to install sbt;

try running "sbt" in command prompt/console,
If you get

```
    Cannot find sbt launcher 0.13.0
Please download: 
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.0/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /home/<your home directory>/.sbt/.lib/0.13.0/sbt-launch.jar
```

then, follow its instructions, everything should work

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt(Not Git-Bash prompt) and run the following commands....

- play clean-all
- play compile
- play run
  Server should be getting started.
  Now come back to IDE(Eclipse) and refresh the project. If problem solved then njoy else try something else :)

Answer (score 0):

May be project/plugins.sbt file you need to update.

Comment: No, this appears to happen during plays bootup itself. As such commands like play run or even play new 'x' was throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you check again once your plugins.sbt, whether is updated or not, like this: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2-RC2"). This is working fine for me.